# Highlighting conditionally based on the date today

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

An Excel worksheet contains a datewise list of entries.  Whenever I open the worksheet, I want today's date entry to be highlighted.  For example, when I open the Excel file containing Interest payment amounts and due dates, it should tell me which Interest is due today.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming. It should be posted on superuser.com, not here.

Comment: @Jean, actually, while I wouldn't do it that way, it could certainly be implemented in VBA.

Comment: Sure, but that can be said about any and everything in Excel, e.g. "How do I add the numbers in cells A1 and A2 and put the result in A3?" Okay, I could do that using VBA, but does that make the question programming-related and fit for SO? Methinks not.

Comment: @pnuts: I agree. But *this* question isn't programming-related. Typing `TODAY` in a conditional formatting dialog box doesn't constitute programming; it falls on the wrong side of the (admittedly fuzzy) line between programming and general software use. And my earlier point was that the whole VBA thing doesn't apply here: The question isn't tagged VBA, and the obvious way to do what the OP wants is using conditional formatting. Implementing a solution in VBA would be awkward and contrived (and not what the OP asked for).

Answer (score 2):

Conditional Formatting is the way to go.

In Excel 2007 (not sure about earlier versions), you can conditional format against formula -- i.e. set a conditional format to equals =TODAY().

(Apologies, I had tried to upload an image for you, but I don't have enough reputation to do so...)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure exactly what you're going for, but if you're attempting to just have the data highlighted you can use conditional formatting to cause the appropriate values to be marked out.

If you're trying to make the data actually be re-ordered or show a sub-set of the existing data onto another tab, you'll need to embed some custom visual basic code into your workbook as a macro-enabled workbook (*.xlsm). There are events inside there that can be called when the workbook is opened.